# Weird 404 URL problem: domain name is being placed at end of URLs in WordPress site according to Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, wordpress, 404

In Google Search Console/Webmaster Tools, I found `404` error URLs with this pattern: `http://example.com/page-name/example.com`

This is happening to all pages, posts, and even category type.

For example:
[image: Screenshot of 404 error in Google Search Console]

Here is the *.htaccess* file:

[image: Screenshot of .htaccess file]

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of your `.htaccess` file as it is that which normally causes redirects such as this. But also you need to clarify what you mean by `For some reason when doing crawl tests` because from the looks if it your not doing a crawl test via the Fetch Tool. Googlebot is renowned for attempting to access non-existent URLs and as long as the fetch test works or a curl test... then you have nothing to worry about... as it says at the bottom `404's don't harm your sites performance in search`.

Comment: If you mean the CRAWL errors found in your Google console then we already have a vast amount of questions and answers already on Pro Webmasters and your question 'may' be considered duplicate, unless something about it is unique and without providing more information its impossible to tell let alone answer.

Comment: Note also that your screenshot shows `domainname.com` appended to the end of the URL, not `http://domainname.com`, as you stated in the preceding paragraph - there's a big difference.

Comment: Did a CURL test on the URL and it works fine and it looks like crawl errors, not test errors. It is also possible that your hosting provider temporarily had glitch which caused Googlebot to be redirected like so, check your access.log, error.log log files for yesterday.

Comment: Your copyright link is missing the scheme: `<a href="costproduct.com">COSTPRODUCT</a>` - that would seem to be your problem, this would result in a URL of the form shown in your screenshot as this will be seen as relative to the current URL, so you will get an 404 from every page. (This at least explains the error in your screenshot, but not your written explanation - unless that's a "typo"?)

Comment: you can view the htaccess file. Question edited.

Comment: I do not know or use WP, however, this sounds familiar like we have gotten this question a few times. If I remember, it is a WP setting that does this and a simple click in the config somewhere will turn it off. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "copyright anchor" in the footer of your page is missing the protocol/scheme (and arguably a URL-path):

```
<a href="example.com">COSTPRODUCT</a> Copyright © 2017
```

This will be seen as a relative URL and will consequently result in an *invalid* link of the form `http://example.com/page-name/example.com`.

> This is happening to all pages, posts, and even category type.

The above link appears on every page, so yes, you will get a similar 404 being reported on every page.